# Hyperledger Iroha Android - CommandService Stateless invalid tx - Wrongly formed creator_account_id, passed value: '' -

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, hyperledger, blockchain, grpc

I'm trying to create an Android app with Hyperledger Iroha. So first user will type `Username` and `Account details` to register an account.

[image]

Here is my [IrohaConnection.kt](https://github.com/truongnmt/iroha-glowing-octo-carnival/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/nguyenmanhtruong/irohatx/IrohaConnection.kt) file to form a request to send to Iroha server. Basically, I just copy and port from Java to Kotlin from this [iroha-android-sample repo](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-android/blob/master/iroha-android-sample/src/main/java/jp/co/soramitsu/iroha/android/sample/interactor/CreateAccountInteractor.java).

This is the message I get from Iroha console:

```
[2018-08-08 01:57:17.221326506][th:35][warning] CommandService Stateless invalid tx: Transaction: [[Transaction should contain at least one command Wrongly formed creator_account_id, passed value: ''. Field should match regex '[a-z_0-9]{1,32}\@([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)*[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?' bad timestamp: too old, timestamp: 0, now: 1533693437216 Quorum should be within range (0, 128] ]]
, hash: 2526b8c49021a34172deb7255509e34b45822c07c822808176498bec1f0cb1fe
[2018-08-08 01:57:17.270612531][th:38][warning] CommandService Stateless invalid tx: Transaction: [[Transaction should contain at least one command Wrongly formed creator_account_id, passed value: ''. Field should match regex '[a-z_0-9]{1,32}\@([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)*[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?' bad timestamp: too old, timestamp: 0, now: 1533693437270 Quorum should be within range (0, 128] ]]
, hash: 2526b8c49021a34172deb7255509e34b45822c07c822808176498bec1f0cb1fe
[2018-08-08 01:57:18.274183120][th:35][warning] CommandService StatusStream request processing timeout, hash: 7e184190581756a5d7192e9491b4f9bf9a33f077ecb0044782a5057aa8212eea
```

It's said that:

- CommandService Stateless invalid tx
- Transaction should contain at least one command
- Wrongly formed creator_account_id, passed value: ''
- bad timestamp: too old, timestamp: 0, now: 1533693437270
- Quorum should be within range (0, 128] ]]

I'm not really understand how Iroha receive variables but when debug I see:

[image]

`createdTime_` , `creatorAccountId_`, `quorum_` these 3 vars has value which is kind of what Iroha ask for, but somehow the server not get it.

Another weird things is, on the sample Iroha-android repo: [build.gradle](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-android/blob/master/iroha-android-sample/build.gradle#L22):

```
release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "iroha_url", "199.247.26.56"
        resValue "integer", "iroha_port", "50051"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "iroha_url", "199.247.26.56"
        resValue "integer", "iroha_port", "50051"
    }
```

You see those IP? When using this default IP `199.247.26.56`, the app work, but when I change to my local IP, which is the same PC - my own Iroha deployment, it's not. I think that on this IP `199.247.26.56`, they have deployed Iroha correctly.

So on that though, I have deploy Iroha following these:

- https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/index.html#starting-iroha-node
- https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/deployment.html#docker
- Build from source: https://hyperledger.github.io/iroha-api/#docker

But still the same error:

- CommandService Stateless invalid tx
- Transaction should contain at least one command
- Wrongly formed creator_account_id, passed value: ''
- bad timestamp: too old, timestamp: 0, now: 1533693437270
- Quorum should be within range (0, 128] ]]

Also shooted an [issue#141](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-android/issues/141) and [issue#1655](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha/issues/1655) already.